# How to switch a sum and an integral with a summation variable in its upper bound?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Recently, I looked at some problems in which the order of summation and integration were reversed to arrive at a solution. I believe the process could be summed up (excuse the pun) in this way:

$$\left.\sum_{n=a}^{b} \int_c^d  f(x,n) \ dx= \int_c^d \sum_{i=a}^{b} f(x,n) \ dx \qquad \right| \ a,b \in \mathbb{N}, c,d \in \mathbb{R}\ \forall\ a<b, c<d $$

where $f(x, n)$ is a function with $x$ and  $n$  inputs and satisfies the respective theorems needed to permit the exchange in order of discrete and continuous sums, to begin with (dominated convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem, etc.).

However, this led me to ponder on how the order of a sum and an integral with its upper bound as this sum's summation variable may be exchanged (now that I have typed it - it probably sounds a bit like nonsense)

Perhaps my question should be as follows:

$$\left.\sum_{n=a}^{b} \int_c^n f(x,n)\ dx = \int_?^? \sum_{n=?}^{?} f(x,n) \ dx \qquad \right| \ c \in \mathbb{R}, a,b \in \mathbb{N}, c ≤ a $$ (although c = a may introduce redundancy on the first term of the first expression)

If it is possible to express the first expression in such a form, please could you tell me? It would be much appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that when the sum has finite bounds, they can be switched easily

Comment: For simplicity, consider the case $c=a$. Essentially, you integrate over all $(x,n)$ subject to the condition that $a\le x\le n\le b$. In the $\sum\int$ variant, you pick $n$ first and $x$ later, so to speak, but the order can be reversed (whether we are allowed to, is a different problem, but fortunately the sums are finite!), so we first pick $x$ with $a\le x\le b$, and then $n$ with $x\le n\le b$: $\int_a^b\sum_{\lceil x\rceil}^bf(x,n)\,\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For context & justification: In general, interchanges of integrals are justified by Fubini's theorem (sums and series are treated as integrals w.r.t. the counting measure). When the integration region is more complicated than a cube, it is often helpful to 'shift' the condition on the integration region into the integrand by multiplying it with the indicator function of the integration region. Then we may integrate over a larger rectangular domain and interchange integrals without complications. After the interchange, we just need to understand in which way the introduced indicator constrains the integration region of the rewritten integral.

Here is how this works in this case:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=a}^{b} \int_c^n f(x,n)\ dx
&= \sum_{n=a}^b ∫_c^b f(x,n)\mathbb{I}_{x \leq n}  \;\mathrm{d}x\\
&= ∫_c^b \sum_{n=a}^b  f(x,n) \mathbb{I}_{x \leq n} \;\mathrm{d}x \\
&= ∫_c^b \sum_{n=\lceil \max(a,x) \rceil}^b f(x,n) \;\mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align*}